# I can't import 'Pandas' to a file while it allows me to import it to another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader

I have opened 3 python files, 2 of them do not allow me to do `import pandas as pd`, while it allows me to do it in another file and it works perfectly in that file.

It tells me "No module named 'pandas'" in those 2 files, I already installed it using `python -m pip install pandas`, and `pip install pandas`, how can I import it without having this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running those 3 files in the same (virtual) environment? Installing pandas into one env does not make it available to a different env. You have to manage packages per environment

Comment: oh wait it worked now, i had to do what you said, thanks